# list files in a directory without listing the ones in the current directory

Tags: sed, grep, find, ls

Say I have a file `*.txt` in a directory `txtpath=/path/to/txt/`.

I would like to list `*.txt` files in `$txtpath` from current directory (not `$txtpath`) without also listing the files in the current directory, as it happens if I execute `ls *.txt $txtpath` .

I manage to list the `*.txt` files only in `$txtpath` with this command: `find $txtpath -name '*.txt' | sed 's/\// /g' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'`

But maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply specify the full path along with the pattern:

```
ls -d -- "${txtpath}"/*.txt
```

Though in effect the *listing* is done by the shell globbing, `ls` ends up just printing the arguments that it receives from the shell. You might as well use `printf` here:

```
printf '%s\n' "${txtpath}"/*.txt
```

Which would give the same result except (in the shells that don't cancel commands upon non-matching globs) in the case where there's no non-hidden `txt` file in the directory.

Comment: actually, your solution does not work for me, `ls: cannot access ${txtpath}*.txt: No such file or directory` (I run your command with no slash because already included in my variable). But an even simpler solution works: just `ls $txtpath*.txt` - thanks for the hint

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I got the quoting wrong; see my updated answer.